# Providing Alternative Bitmaps !! How to recognize that initially in which bucket/drawable we need to put our image

Tags: android, drawable, android-bitmap, android-resource-qualifiers

**Hello Androider's**, I need your little help I developed many applications but from the beginning I was confused on this thing.

Suppose I have an image or a bunch of images with **different resolutions**. How to know in which drawable I need to put it in initially.

For example, if you have a bitmap drawable that's 412x371 pixels for medium-density screens, then we can easily scale it for other buckets according to this 3:4:6:8:12:16 scaling ratio.
But how we know that 412x371 would be suitable for medium-density. We can put it in HDPI too.

> So now I have couple of images that I want to use in my project but
> how to know which image I need to put it in which bucket initially so
> after that I would be able to calculate for other density buckets.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First

[Android Image bake](https://asset-generator.netlify.app/)

Upload your file to.

Then, after downloading it as zip, select your files from the ResourceManager in Android Studio by clicking Import Drawable. That's the whole process. You don't have to worry.

Comment: I am talking about images not the icons. My image size is 412x371 and i want to use it as a background image in activity. but your website is converting it into icons of  with default ratio. 48*48 , 36 * 36 and so on.

Comment: You can open the relevant image file with sketch and export it.

Comment: My designer is creating design in Adobe XD for both IOS and Android. And he is using iphone 11 pro max frame for design. While exporting images for Android there is a option mdpi 100% , hdpi , XXHDPI, XXXHDPI and he not  familar which option he should select and then according to that adobe will scale assets for other buckets.

Comment: You can examine the "image rendering "section. https://exportkit.com/plugin/environments/xml/convert-xd-to-android-studio